# How do you measure the number of open database connections

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, connection

I am trying to determine if I have a database connection leak.
So I need to see the number of open connections.
I have some simple test code that creates a leak:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;UID=sa;PWD=fjg^%kls;Initial Catalog=ABC");
    sql.Open();
  }

}
```

Note there is no .Close and this does infact crash after being run 3 times in quick succession.

In order to measure the leak I am running the Performance monitor and measuring SQLServer: General Statistics/User Connections:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/counter.png))</sub>

However, these seem to be zero when I run my code:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/counter1.jpg))</sub>

What should I change to actually see the connections?

**ANSWER**

I have approved an answer below. Even though it doesn't use the performance tools, its good enough for my use. Bottom line is I wanted to see how many connections remain open after opening a web page and this did the trick.

Comment: What does "ASP.NET SQL" mean? If it's just two tags, then please leave them ou of the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try running a query against the master db like this:

```
SELECT SPID,
       STATUS,
       PROGRAM_NAME,
       LOGINAME=RTRIM(LOGINAME),
       HOSTNAME,
       CMD
FROM  MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
WHERE DB_NAME(DBID) = 'TEST' AND DBID != 0
```

See [this link](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-3-Determining_number_of_open_connections_in_your_connection_pools.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the [`sp_who`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260384%28SQL.80%29.aspx) stored proc?  If there are stale open connections they should show up there.

To show just the `sa` users processes run:

```
EXEC sp_who 'sa'
```

Comment: Does that mean I can't see the connections in the Performance graph?